# How to Manage Dynamic Relationships?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, activerecord

I need help creating an appropriate database structure that will allow me to dynamically create "fields" and "values". I plan on using the following 5 tables.

1. TraitCategories
2. Groups
3. TraitGroupings
4. People
5. TraitValues

`TraitCategories` table holds *only* categories (i.e. "fields") of traits -- i.e. hair color, height, etc. -- and the categories can be added/removed as desired.

`Groups` table holds ad hoc/dynamic group labels -- i.e. Asian, South American, etc.

`TraitGroupings` is the join table for `TraitCategories` and `Groups`

The `People` table will be linked to the `Groups` table via a foreign key and thus will be assigned various categories (fields) of traits by leveraging the relationship between the `Groups` and `TraitCategories` tables.

But the question is, how do I assign **per person** values to the trait categories/fields?

I was thinking of having each row in the `TraitValues` table contain `person_id` and `trait_category_id` so that there will be a relationship between the `TraitValues` table and both the `People` and `TraitCategories` tables. Does this approach make sense? Will this approach allow me to get trait categories and values via the `People` table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are describing a form of [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).

I'm not sure how practical this is going to be for representing in Ruby, but in you case, the database model would look similar to this:

[image]

*(Most non-key fields omitted, for brevity.)*

Note how we abundantly use the identifying relationships. This is what lets us propagate `GroupId` down both sides of the "diamond-shaped" dependency, and merge it into a single field at the bottom, in `TraitValue`.

This is what ensures a person cannot have a trait, unless it is also listed for that person's group. For example, a person can have a "hair color" **only** if the person's group has the "hair color" as well.

---

BTW...

> The People table will be linked to the TraitGroupings via a foreign key -- and thus will be assigned various categories (fields) of traits.

If `People` has a FK that directly references `TraitGroupings`, then a person can have at most one trait grouping and therefore at most one trait category. From the wording of your question, that desn't appear to be what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the clear and detailed answer; it's very helpful. You're correct in your `BTW` section I meant to write `Groups` **not** `TraitGroupings`.

Comment: After further reflecting on your diagram, I'm unclear as to why you reference the `TraitGroups` table from the `TraitValue` table (via a FK), rather than directly reference the `TraitCategory` table from the `TraitValue` table. Could you further explain/elaborate?

Comment: @Ari Because `TraitValue` is specific to `TraitGroup` and not `TraitCategory`. In other words, you need to "register" a trait category with the group, before you can assign it a value. Assuming my understanding of your requirements was correct, of course...